# Why do stream-cons and cons behave differently?

Tags: list, sequences

I am trying to create a lazy sequence of the lines in the current buffer using the [stream.el](https://nicolas.petton.fr/blog/stream.html) library. These two recursive functions both read the lines of the current buffer from point to the end of the buffer. The first function collects the lines in a list, the second creates a "lazy list", which means the buffer lines aren't read until they are needed.

```lisp
(defun lines-to-list ()
  (unless (eobp)
    (cons (prog1
            (thing-at-point 'line t)
            (next-line))
          (lines-to-list))))

(defun lines-as-stream ()
  (unless (eobp)
    (stream-cons (prog1
                   (thing-at-point 'line t)
                   (next-line))
                 (lines-as-stream))))
```

My problem is that the `lines-as-stream` function never includes the last line of the buffer. I have the following test lines in the current buffer:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

with point on `1` and a newline after `5`. When I run `lines-to-list`, I get a nice list with five elements: `("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")` (the strings also include newlines, but I have omitted them for readability). However, when I evaluate `(seq-length (lines-as-stream))` in the minibuffer, I get the value 4. I have also tried `(seq-into (lines-as-stream) 'list)`, which I expected to return the same list as before, but I only getting `("1", "2", "3", "4")` (newlines omitted again). Curiously, in both cases the cursor ends up on the empty line after the `5`, which would indicate that both functions have processed all the lines.

What am I missing? Why is the stream version not returning the last line when evaluated?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream library requires you to return `(stream-empty)` instead of nil when reaching the end of the buffer. The following function returns the empty stream when point is at the end of the buffer.

```lisp
(defun lines-as-stream ()
  (if (eobp)
      (stream-empty)
    (stream-cons (prog1
                   (thing-at-point 'line t)
                   (forward-line 1))
                 (lines-as-stream))))
```

Some people might find this to be a more elegant solution:

```lisp
(defun lines-as-stream ()
  (if (eobp)
      (stream-empty)
    (stream-cons (thing-at-point 'line t) (progn
                                            (forward-line 1)
                                            (lines-as-stream)))))
```